# How to extract cells starting with a certain pattern located in different columns using unix or R

Tags: r, perl, unix

I am new to unix and am trying to learn the basics. 
I have a tab-delimited file. I want to extract the cells starting with "txGN=" pattern, and print them in a new column within the corresponding row. These cells are located in different columns. The number of columns are not the same in all rows. These values are present in most rows, but not in all.

This is how the file looks:

```
chr1  880942  taPN=-1    taWT=3       txGN=SAMD11   txID=uc001abw   FUNC=nonsyn
chr1  894573  txDN=-3    txGN=NOC2L   txID=uc003    intronic
chr1  10626   txDN=-9    txID=uc2     txST=+
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Should provide example of desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "unix" but if that includes commands commonly found on a unix-based system, how about a simple Perl script? Apply the following to your file

```
perl -ne 'print /txGN=([^\s]+)/ ? "$1\t$_" : "\t$_";' your-file
```

to get

```
SAMD11  chr1    880942  taPN=-1     taWT=3       txGN=SAMD11
NOC2L   chr1    894573  txDN=-655   txGN=NOC2L   txID=uc001aby.3
        chr1    1062638 txDN=-9758  txID=uc2     txST=+
```

A little rewriting could place the new column elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
#count maximum number of columns in the "file"
maxcol <- max(count.fields("D:/file.txt")) 

x <- read.table("D:/file.txt",as.is=TRUE,fill=TRUE,col.names=1:maxcol)
x[x==""]<-NA
indices<-which(substr(as.matrix(x),start=1,stop=5)=="txGN=",arr.ind=TRUE)

x<-cbind(x,NA)
for(i in 1:nrow(indices)){
  na1<-which(is.na(x[indices[i,1],]))[1]
  x[indices[i,1],na1]<-x[indices[i,1],indices[i,2]] 
}
x
    X1     X2      X3         X4          X5            X6          X7          NA
1 chr1 880942 taPN=-1     taWT=3 txGN=SAMD11 txID=uc001abw FUNC=nonsyn txGN=SAMD11
2 chr1 894573 txDN=-3 txGN=NOC2L  txID=uc003      intronic  txGN=NOC2L        <NA>
3 chr1  10626 txDN=-9   txID=uc2      txST=+          <NA>        <NA>        <NA>

#If you want to "remove" NA's:
x[is.na(x)]<-""
```

EDIT:

Here's a version which does not create the data frame in R (in order to reduce the memory requirements), instead it appends results into new file:

```
maxcol <- max(count.fields("D:/file.txt")) 
maxrow <- length(readLines("D:/file.txt")) 
# bit inefficient, we read the whole file to get the number of lines 

stepsize<-50 # how many lines are read at once
k<-0
while(TRUE){
  if((k+1)*stepsize > maxrow){
    x <- read.table("D:/file.txt",as.is=TRUE,fill=TRUE,col.names=1:maxcol,
                    skip=k*stepsize,nrow=maxrow-k*stepsize+1)
  } else  x <- read.table("D:/file.txt",as.is=TRUE,fill=TRUE,
                          col.names=1:maxcol, skip=k*stepsize,nrow=stepsize)

  if(nrow(x)==0) break #end loop when finished
  x[x==""]<-NA
  indices<-which(substr(as.matrix(x),start=1,stop=5)=="txGN=",arr.ind=TRUE)
  x<-cbind(x,NA)
  for(i in 1:nrow(indices)){
    na1<-which(is.na(x[indices[i,1],]))[1]
    x[indices[i,1],na1]<-x[indices[i,1],indices[i,2]] 
  }
  # New stuff, change sep and eol if needed
  write.table(x, file = "D:/filenew.txt", append = TRUE, quote = FALSE, 
          sep = " ", eol = "\n", na = "",row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
  k<-k+1
}

read.table("D:/filenew.txt",as.is=TRUE,fill=TRUE,col.names=1:(maxcol+1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.I forgot to say that the number of columns are not the same for all rows, and the number of characters within cells are different

Comment: It does not matter if there is different number of characters in cells if the first 5 characters are the ones which can contain the wanted string. But second issue is bit more tricky..

Comment: Thank you.In addition, I wanted to print the extracted value into a new column within the corresponding row.

Comment: @user2162153 I updated my answer, is that what you would like to have?

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly fine for small data. The problem though is that the file I am working on is big ~ 80Mb, and I get this error "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 42.1 Mb". I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: @user2162153 That's weird, it doesn't sound that big data. At which point does the error occur, when you read the data or later? You could perhaps process the file in chunks using `skip` and `nrow` arguments for `read.table`.

Comment: @user2162153 Added a solutions regarding my last comment.

Comment: Thank you very much. It appears that there is something missing in the last version as it does not run.

Comment: @user2162153 corrected, I accidentally edited few rows away as I cleaned the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Today, I have run your code a couple of times, but due to unclear reasons, it stops running near the end of run. For sure, your code works perfectly fine! There may be problems with the server. I greatly appreciate your help.